# Trouble getting div layer and javascript to delay a few seconds after page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, delay, settimeout

I've been trying to get this script to delay a few seconds after the page loads, but haven't been able to get it to work. I know there are other similar questions on here that appear to be answered, but I've tried implementing their solutions and haven't had any luck so far.

I really appreciate any help you can offer. Thanks in advance!

```
<script>
$.fn.rotate = function(){
return this.each(function() {
var $children = $(this).children();
var position = -1;
!function loop() {
    position = (position + 1) % $children.length;
    $children.eq(position)
             .fadeIn(1000)
             .delay(7000)
             .fadeOut(1000, loop);
}();
});
};

function show() {
AB = document.getElementById('.bannergroup');
AB.style.display = 'inline';
}
setTimeout("show()", 5000);

$(function(){
$(".banneritem").hide();
$(".bannergroup").rotate();
});  

</script>
```

Comment: When you say that you haven't been able to get it to work, what exactly do you mean? What is it doing and what are you hoping for it to do? You might try posting a fiddle to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: @GreatBigBore I'm trying to get a div layer which is a list with some list items and some css transitions to display and start it's transitions a few seconds after the page loads, rather than immediately on page load. You can see what it looks like here – http://webpresario.com/finishit/ It's in second section of the page where the image of the guy with a quote appears and disappears. Each image of him is a list item that is included in one main div. I want that main div (.bannergroup) to have a delay before it appears.

Comment: Hmm, do you mean the guy in the 'Post a challenge' section? Looking at your source, it seems that the list items are images of tips, not of the guy. Anyway, I take it you want the guy and the div to be invisible until a few seconds after page load? Does your css have all that stuff hidden? I mean, where in your js/css/html are you hiding the guy and the tips before your js can run?

Comment: @GreatBigBore This javascript is affecting the list items which are the images of the tips. Correct, I do want the div that contains the list items to be invisible until a few seconds after page load. The image of the man isn't part of this scenario. He's fine where he is lol. All the js that is affecting the list items is at the bottom of the page before the end body tag </body>.

Comment: I copied your divs and your $() to a fiddle, and it works as you wanted: visible dude, invisible tips. I recommend the divide-and-conquer approach: strip out everything but those divs, test your page, ensure that it works like that, and then start adding stuff back in and see when it breaks. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
$(function () {
```

is a short for the more expressive [jQuery(document).ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) function, handling cross-browser comfortable the [DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/DOMContentLoaded) event:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

    // this is the place (to delay something)
    // after page parsed / document ready:
    setTimeout(show, 5000);
});
```

Another loading event is (also known as `window.onload`)

```
jQuery(window).load(function () {

    // this is the place
    // after page and html images are loaded
});
```

I see you also try to select elements by a typical class identifier `.bannergroup`, for which you would have to use `getElementsByClassName('bannergroup')` (without the dot).
However because you have jQuery, let's do it easy:

```
function show() {
    $('.bannergroup').css({ display: 'inline' });
    // now .rotate()?
}
```

Comment: Well not otherwise; there is said, that document ready is the moment, when `body` is parsed, and this maybe before images are downloaded.

Comment: My bad. From http://api.jquery.com/ready/ : All three of the following syntaxes are equivalent:

$(document).ready(handler)
$().ready(handler) (this is not recommended)
$(handler)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @metadings. I'm a little confused about how to implement this. I'm new to javascript. Do I need to put all my original javascript code within...

    function show() {
    $('.bannergroup').css({ display: 'inline' });
    // now .rotate()?
    } 

Also, how do I set the timed delay in this scenario?

Comment: you should replace your code in the lines i mentioned... the first ones i didn't touch. the setTimeout's delay is currently 5000 ms

Comment: @metadings Hi, I've been trying to add this code and replacing the lines you suggest to replace, but it hasn't work for me yet. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Hi, please update your code above and make a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) so I can see how it finally should look like

Answer (score 0):

looking at your above scenario i think you want to call the function when all elements finish loading in the page. If its so you can use :

```
    $(window).load(function(){
    //executes only when all the elements in the page finish loading like images.
     //write your stuff here 
    });
```

if this is not the case the answer suggested by metadinings must be helpful.
thanks

Comment: Correct. I would like there to be a 10 second delay after the page has loaded. I've been trying to add the above code plus the setTimeout function, but no luck so far. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.